# Edge incident to cut-vertex not in perfect matching of a graph

Tags: graphs, matching

Let ***G = (V,E)*** be a connected graph and ***a ∈ V*** be an articulation point of ***G***. How can be proved that there is an edge ***e ∈ G*** incident with ***a*** with the property that e doesn't belong to a perfect matching of ***G***?

Let's say that there are two vertices ***u,v ∈ G*** so that the only paths between them go through ***a***. Then there is no edge directly connecting ***u*** and ***v***. It means that ***a*** has at least 2 vertices(which is pretty obvious) and knowing that the property of a perfect matching is that the degree of any vertex is equal to 1, it means that there is at least one edge incident to ***a*** that doesn't belong to the perfect matching. But I'm not sure, is it okay?

Comment: Cf. http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66882/edge-not-in-a-perfect-matching-of-a-connected-graph.

Comment: I saw it and I tried to do it myself but it seems that I'm stuck and the post in the link is already put on hold.